# Verify order of mock calls

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I need to test if one objects calls other object methods in right order.
Unfortunately it looks like  Mockito use some kind of grouping for calls with the same parameters. I prepared example which illustrates this behavior.

```
public class TestInOrder {

@Test
public void test() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Bar mockBar = mock(Bar.class);
    foo.run(mockBar);

    InOrder order = Mockito.inOrder(mockBar);
    order.verify(mockBar).A();
    order.verify(mockBar).B();
    order.verify(mockBar).B();
    order.verify(mockBar).A();
    order.verify(mockBar).B();
    }
}

class Foo {

void run(Bar mockBar) {
    mockBar.A();
    mockBar.B();
    mockBar.B();
    mockBar.A();
    mockBar.B();
}

}

class Bar {
public void A() {
}

public void B() {
}
}
```

The result is:

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.verification.VerificationInOrderFailure: 
Verification in order failure:
bar.B();
Wanted 1 time:
-> at com.goeuro.pi.provider.busfor.TestInOrder.test(TestInOrder.java:19)
But was 3 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at com.goeuro.pi.provider.busfor.Foo.run(TestInOrder.java:32)
```

I don't understand why I get this error. Order of calls in test is the same as in method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you expect one invocation on each mock. Instead `Mockito` will count all the invocation on certain mock and will fail when 2 in a row will happen. 
This is the implementation for verify method in `InOrderImpl` class.

```
public <T> T verify(T mock) {
    return this.verify(mock, VerificationModeFactory.times(1));
}
```

As you can see, it tells `mockito` to expect exact one invocation on method.
From JavaDoc:

> Allows verifying exact number of invocations.

Use [VerificationMode](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.26/org/mockito/verification/VerificationMode.html) to tell Mockito how to verify you mock. This should help:

```
InOrder order = Mockito.inOrder(mockBar);
order.verify(mockBar).A();
order.verify(mockBar, times(2)).B();
order.verify(mockBar).A();
order.verify(mockBar).B();
```